# Is there a way to instantiate a datetime object in a timezone other than local?

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

I've been racking my brain all afternoon trying to figure this one out.  Essentially, the problem itself seems simple.  I'm given a date/time that is representative of a date and time in another time zone (not local).  I want to convert this value to a UTC value to store in the database.  However, all of the methods I find online seem to point to you either starting with UTC or starting with a local time zone.  You can convert TO other time zones from these, but you can't start with anything other than those.  As a result, it appears that I'll have to do some kind of convoluted offset math to do what I want.  Here is an example of the problem:

```
var dateString = "8/20/2014 6:00:00 AM";
DateTime date1 = DateTime.Parse(dateString, 
                      System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var currentTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time");

// Now the server is set to Central Standard Time, so any automated offset calculation that it runs will come from that point of view:
var utcDate = date1.ToUniversalTime; // This is wrong

// Similarly, if I try to reverse-calculate it, it doesn't work either
var convertedDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(date1, currentTimeZone);
utcDate = convertedDate.ToUniversalTime; // This is also wrong
```

In essence, I want to somehow tell the system that the datetime object I'm currently working with *is* from that time zone other than local, so that I know the conversion will be correct.  I know that I'll eventually need to figure Daylight Savings Time in there, but that is a problem for another day.

Comment: Never call any of the conversion function from the `DateTime` object itself.  They only understand local and UTC.  Instead, use the methods from the `TimeZoneInfo` object, as Jonathan M suggested in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb382770(v=vs.110).aspx) method be of any use to you ?

> The TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime method converts a time from one time zone
>   to another.

Alternatively, you could use the `ConvertTimeToUtc` method to simply convert any date (specifying the source time zone) to UTC.

```
var dateString = "8/20/2014 6:00:00 AM";
DateTime date1 = DateTime.Parse(dateString, 
                      System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var currentTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time");

var utcDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(date1, currentTimeZone);
```

Comment: I understand your response, but I don't think it directly addresses the question.  Yes, using TimeZoneInfo is the better way to convert to another time zone.  My problem is that the original date string is for a time zone that I'm not currently in.  I need to make the system understand that so that when I call ConvertTimeToUtc, it will be converting it from the proper time zone, not the one the server is using as reference.

Comment: Apologies - I didn't make the connection last night when I read over the code - I saw it through the lens of what I'd already done and didn't see the connection.  I'll give the second piece of code a shot when I get to work.  Thank you!

Comment: Integrating with Jeppe's answer, if your date variable has the kind set to either _local_ or _universal_, you might need to change it to _unspecified_ first by using the [DateTime.SpecifyKind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.specifykind(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Comment: Jonathan M - looks like your answer was what we were looking for.  We danced all around it, but never quite nailed it.  Thank you for piercing the fog on this one.

Answer (score 1):

The `System.DateTime` struct only has *two bits* for storing the "kind" information. That is why you can only have "local" or "universal" or "unknown" (or "magicl local").

Take a look at the `System.DateTimeOffset` struct. It is like a `DateTime`, but it also keeps the time zone (offset from (plus or minus) UTC).

Comment: I suspected that I might have to go the offset route to get what I want, as everything I was researching was leading me to the same conclusion you listed above (the two bits - here or UTC).  Thank you for the information.  I'll look into that first thing tomorrow.